# How to create objects with macros in R?

Tags: r, macros, data.table

Let's say I have 10 folders with 10 files of .csv data in each folder.
Let's say folders are named by year from 2011 to 2020 and within each folder, the `data_.csv` files are indexed by 1 to 10.
Thus, the structure of the files are `year/data_.csv`.

I would like to read the 10 `data_.csv` from each folder and create `year_data_1` to `year_data_10` with each file, where `year` goes from `2011` to `2020`.
Then append 10 files from the same year together and create `year_data`.

What I am doing is the following

```
library(data.table)

years = c(2011:2020)

for (i in seq(along = years)) {
    for (j in 1:10) {
        as.name(paste0(i, "_data_", j)) <- fread(paste0(i, "/data_", j, ".csv"))
    }
}
```

It does not work properly, however.

Comment: instead of a for loop use lapply(), then use rbindlist() on the output

Comment: You need to use `assign(name, value)`, you can't use `as.name(name) <- value`.  But you're better off putting things in a list or other structure rather than all separate variables.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks, but can you please elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 3):

How about building the filenames first as a parameter grid and iterating over it?

```
files <- CJ(years = 2011:2020, idx = 1:10)
files[, path := file.path(years, sprintf("data_%d.csv", idx))]

year_data <- rbindlist(lapply(files$path, fread))
```